# Mongodb C# driver Insert new child of object to parents

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I want to insert new child on the record below and i use this code on .net core

```
            var builder = Builders<parent>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq("_id", "123");
            var update = Builders<parent>.Update.AddToSet<IEnumerable<Child>> 
            ("Child", Child);

            await _expensesContext.collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);

  parent
  {
   "_Id": "123"
    "Child": [
    {"Id": "1234", "name": "jhon"}
    ]
  }
```

but i enconter this error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[child]' to type 'Child'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using `addtosetEach` instead of `addtoset`:

```
 var builder = Builders<parent>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq("_id", "123");
            var update = Builders<parent>.Update.AddToSetEach<IEnumerable<Child>> 
            ("Child", Child);

            await _Context.collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```